# Jquery file upload progress bar not redirecting to PHPMailer handler file

Tags: php, jquery

I am using this `jquery` script [Show A Progressbar When Uploading A File - progress-upload.js](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Progressbar-Uploading-File.html) to install a file upload progress bar in a form to be used with `PHPMailer`. Everything is working fine except that once the form is submitted, instead of redirecting to the form action file (ACTION="form-handler.php") it remains on the same page and the progress bar after reaching 100 resets to 0. The form is submitted and the file is also attached successfully but it does not redirect to "form-handler.php".

HTML Form:

```
<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="form-handler.php" name="case-history" id="case-history" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="attach_file[]" id="file_att" class="file_upload" required>
<p><span id="file_error"></span>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="casehistory-submit">
</form>
```

Have placed this before the form:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384-tsQFqpEReu7ZLhBV2VZlAu7zcOV+rXbYlF2cqB8txI/8aZajjp4Bqd+V6D5IgvKT" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<script src="js/progress-bar/src/jquery-progress-upload.js"></script>
```

And placed this after the form:

```
<script>
$('#file_att').setProgressedUploader({
  onInit: function (elements) {
    // triggered on init
  },
  onGetFile: function (elements) {
    // triggered on get file
     },
  onStartSubmitting: function (elements) {
    // triggered when starting uploading
  },
  onProcessing: function (elements) {
    // triggered when processing

  },
  onFinish: function (elements, data) {
    // triggered on finish
  },
  onError: function(e){
    // triggered on error
  }
});
</script>
```

What else do I need to do, to go to "form-handler.php" after form submission. Perhaps some code in here:

```
onFinish: function (elements, data) {
    // triggered on finish
  },
```

but cannot figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
onFinish: function (elements, data) {
       window.location.replace("PATH_HERE/form-handler.php");

  },
```

Comment: it redirects in this case but I receive two emails one with form data and one without. Also get array_keys() and foreach() error defined in form-handler.php